# Error while initializing SparkSession on pyspark

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, python-poetry

**So before I start I just wanna do a little disclaimer: yes, there's a bunch of similar questions here in SO but none of them seems to solve my problem, that's why I'm asking...*

So I bought got a brand new notebook (macOS Monterey with a M1 chip) and I'm trying to install pyspark in it using poetry. So I created a poetry project with the following dependencies:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "data-engineer-demo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = "^1.3.4"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
ipykernel = "^6.5.0"
pyspark = "^3.2.0"
jupyterlab = "^3.2.3"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Everything was installed with the poetry install command. Also, I installed the Java SDK:

```
>> java --version

java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But the problem comes when I try to create a new SparkSession. If I try to execute the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/11/15 15:47:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3s/6_6gpz19035_h6wfd0j9hzsc0000gn/T/ipykernel_14862/2871868459.py in <module>
      1 spark = (
----> 2     SparkSession
      3     .builder
      4     .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
      5     .getOrCreate()

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    226                             sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227                         # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228                         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230                     # by all sessions.

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    390         with SparkContext._lock:
    391             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 392                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    393             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    394 

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    144         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145         try:
--> 146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
    147                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    148         except:

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    207 
    208         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 209         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    210         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    211         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    327         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    328         """
--> 329         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    330 
    331     @classmethod

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1571 
   1572         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1573         return_value = get_return_value(
   1574             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1575 

~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0xfe48b45) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0xfe48b45
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I also tried to see what happened if I just called the pyspark command within terminal and the error log shows up with some minimal diferences:

```
(data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8) flpncc@Felipes-MacBook-Air data-engineer-demo % pyspark
Python 3.8.9 (default, Aug  3 2021, 19:21:54)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/11/15 15:50:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/11/15 15:50:01 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
  warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1573, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/flpncc/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/data-engineer-demo-azP9LM2M-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing the same one.